# Are there any protected file types that would return 404 when accessed by a site running WebMatrix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, webmatrix

For example, in an external JavaScript file I have this inside a simple $(document).ready function:

```
$.getJSON("/aTest.json", function (jsonObj) {
    $("#testJSONBtn").click(function () {
        var val = "";
        for (var i = 0; i <= jsonObj.events.length; ++i) {
            val += jsonObj.events[i].title + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].date + ", " + jsonObj.events[i].explanation + "<br/>";
        }
        $("#JSONOutput").append(val);
    });
});
```

JavaScript console keeps telling me that the server returned 404 (not found), however the file is definitely exactly that name, and exactly on that path. All other resources are accessed by the site just fine. I have tried moving the file around and renaming it, and a slew of other things, so I get the feeling that maybe this has something to do with WebMatrix, the version of IIS that its running (is it 8?), or the file extension I am using (.json).  Aren't external json files supposed to be stored in a file with the .json extension?

**Additional Peculiarity:**

I once had two files with the same name, one was the .json file and the other was.cshtml, and they were in the same directory. During this time the above function didn't return a 404, in fact, it returned nothing at all... It did nothing, but it returned no errors.

If it matters, all ids and selectors have been quintuple checked (and beyond).

Is there something wrong with the above function somehow, or will an external .js file (or WebMatrix's IIS) not access another external .json file like this?

Comment: Do you have any kind of url rewriting enabled? is IIS setup to properly serve .json files with the correct mimetype?(no by default)

Comment: @Kevin B Nothing has been especially configured for it, but I wouldn't expect WebMatrix to need it, but idk. As for the url rewriting, not that I know of

Comment: See the second half of the comment, sorry i edited it.

Comment: No, I haven't done anything. Is that necessary? Also, are you familiar with WebMatrix? Or are you speaking about IIS in general?

Comment: You'll need to go into your IIS settings then and add the json file extension with the application/json mimetype. Or, just change the file extension to .js or .txt

Comment: @KevinB Okay, dumb question: Are you talking about the neat little WebMatrix GUI Settings button, or something within the IIS directory that it uses, itself. Like command line stuff?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebMatrix, but the setting is within IIS itself. See either of the two existing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a static mapping for *.json files in your applicationHost.config.  This post does a nice job explaining how to add a mime type to IIS Express:

http://www.tomasmcguinness.com/2011/07/06/adding-support-for-svg-to-iis-express/

You can also check out the IIS Express logs to see if there are more details in the log.  They're usually located at ~\Documents\IISExpress\Logs

Happy Coding!

Comment: So far, this answer seems the most relevant to WebMatrix. Give me a sec to check it out, and I'll be back!

Comment: EDITED -- Sorry about that, I think I found something that answered that, but I haven't found what mime type json files are, yet. I will look...

Comment: You would want to use something like this:  appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.json',mimeType='application/json']

Comment: I tried application/json and text/json (also, just so you know, I didn't forget to set the fileExtension='json') but it still gives me the Object not supported message.

Comment: It appears that it is, in fact, 'application/json' but alas it isn't working, yet. Let me double check for typos.

Comment: Well, I didn't have the spaces in the right place, but now I'm getting  a different formatting error. There may be a way to do this in a cshtml file, though, I shall check. Thank you very much for all of your help!! Is it against the rules to accept an answer on the grounds that you really got me going in the right direction, even if not solving the entire problem?

Comment: I tried again for the heck of it, and it didn't give me the other strange error. It seems to have worked! By that I mean that it's not giving me a 404 anymore. It's giving me a different error now, but that's likely a formatting issue in the json file or something (although I don't see how, I mean it looks right, but anyway...) So it seems that you did answer my question, after all! Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

**You need to add a valid MIME type for .json files to a Web site or directory.**
For that folow the below steps

1. In IIS Manager, right-click the Web site or Web site directory for
   which you want to add a MIME type, and click Properties.
2. Click the HTTP Headers tab.
3. Click Mime Types.
4. Click New.
5. In the Extension box, type the file name extension. (ie `.json`)
6. In the MIME type box, type a description that exactly matches the
   file type defined on the computer. If you define a MIME type that
   has already been defined at a higher level, you are prompted to
   select the level where the MIME type should reside. Note that you can use the mime type as `text/plain`.
7. Click OK.

**If you are having WebMatrix on IIS Express, follow theses steps**

1. Open a console application with administrator privilages.
2. Navigation to the IIS Express directory. This lives under Program
   Files or Program Files (x86)
3. Run the command appcmd set config /section:staticContent
   /+[fileExtension='json',mimeType='text/plain']

Comment: Funny thing is, WebMatrix is different, for instance, I can take website visitors just fine, but I have no IIS Manager.

Comment: I literally have no IIS Manager :( Sounds silly but it is a WebMatrix peculiarity. Not to say that I probably couldn't install it along with IIS (7, I think), but if I'm not mistaken, properly coordinating WebMatrix with traditional IIS is a whole 'nother beast.

Comment: Just incase someone comes here to check for an answer, mimeType='application/json' is the proper thing to use, +1'd the post anyway as this saved me alot of hassle